# what does /* in sql means?

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen a piece of sql injection example code like below, what does the '/*' in sql means?

```
$_POST['username'] = chr(0xbf) . chr(0x27) . ' OR username = username /*';

$_POST['password'] = 'guess';

$mysql['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);

$mysql['password'] = addslashes($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM   users WHERE  username = '{$mysql['username']}' AND password = '{$mysql['password']}'";

$result = $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/*` is the beginning of a comment. `*/` ends the comment. The attacker is trying to comment out the remainder of the query.

Comment: but it need an <code>*/</code> to end it, isn't it? only <code>/*</code> made the sql to be wrong.

Comment: @xdazz: The way you've posted it in your question, the attack looks like it would result in a query with no closing comment token. Imagine though, that an attacker included `*/` in the password field. You can see how that could end the comment and result in a properly formed query with the attacker's code injected.

Comment: Comments can stay open, they therefore stretch over the end.

Comment: @hakre `/*` comments can stay open is for the old version of mysql, now it is not supported, Maybe for the security reason.

Answer (score 0):

`/*` begins a comment, so everything after that is ignored until a `*/` is encountered

Your attacker introduced an open comment, thereby nullifying the effect of the password check

Answer (score 0):

/* means a start of a multiline comment

For example:

```
/*

CREATE PROC A_SAMPLE_PROC

BEGIN

AS
SELECT * FROM A_SAMPLE_TABLE
END

*/
```

while `--` means single line comment. Keyboard shortcut for commenting in MS SQL Server Studio is `Ctrl + K, Ctrl + C`